# What is the VESA:WRESTLER driver and why am I using it?

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

I just installed the proprietary `fglrx-updates` driver:

[image]

However, when I check the Graphics, it's shown to be VESA:WRESTLER:

[image]

What is this VESA:WRESTLER driver and why am I using it? Is it just another name for the `fglrx-updates` driver? Or is it a different thing?

Comment: I think `Wrestler` is the codename for `HD 6290`, but the thing I don't understand is the `VESA`. When I Googled it, I found that `VESA` is a "Generic video driver". So is it the same as 'fglrx'?

Comment: so do you also use the `fglrx` driver? And what does it show up on your `Graphics` page?

Answer (score 0):

Wrestler is a code name AMD/ATI gave to that model. I found this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units) article that has loads of names.

[image]

[fxglr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Catalyst) is a display driver so a piece of software to drive your videocard. So something different ;)

> fglrx is the name of the Linux display driver used for ATI Radeon and ATI FireGL family of video adapters and stands for "FireGL and Radeon for X". It contains both free and open-source and proprietary parts. Starting from Catalyst 7.11, the ATI Proprietary Linux driver was renamed ATI Catalyst Linux.

So one (wrestler) is the name of a piece of hardware that the other one (fglrx) can use to use your display.

[VESA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA) is an organisation (Video Electronics Standards Association) and they define and create standards as their name implies.

Comment: my question specifically asks about `VESA`, what it means and the difference between it and the `fglrx` driver. You don't seem to address anything about `VESA` at all. Yes, I know `VESA:WRESTLER` is the name of the driver, it's shown in the image. And what I want to know is `is it different from fglrx and how`